# how to do database hot bbackup?

Tags: database, backup, database-backups

so I am learning about databases and still fairly new

but from what I learned so far I gathered that if the database is large then hot backup should be used not cold backup. (from my understanding hot backup is when you backup database while users are still using it , cold is when you need to have a downtime to do the backup- users can't use it)

but when you have somewhat large files (eg. PDFs of size 20M?) stored in some directory and you store the paths for the files inside the database ... if you need to do a hot backup how would you go about backing up those files??

what approaches should be used and do they have down sides?
is it possible to do a hot backup for them? if not then why!

also does it really matter what type of database is used?? (MySQL vs sqlserver ,...)
or is it a general approach for any type?

I have already googled this and got no answers! (maybe I am using the wrong terms? please point out the right ones!!!!)

if you think my question is too general please point me out in the right direction

please excuse my English as it is not my first language 
I appreciate any help I can get

Comment: Can you explain what is `Cold` and `Hot` backup of database. And how database backup is related to files in system?

Comment: I have edited the question regarding hot and cold backups ,   

since you store file paths inside your database it only makes since you should backup the files as well because logically they should have been inside the database and put them outside because they make it too large and harder to maintain

Comment: Just copy file via FTP, do some exporting jobs via PhpMyAdmin and you still have working web bage, while backuping everything. And you never put files to database, just references to them

Answer (score 0):

**How to make backup of live webpage:**
1) Copy all files from `FTP` to your local machine, write them to some DVD or place somewhere safe.
2) Go to PhpMyAdmin > `Export` > press <kbd>Go</kbd>
*If database is big, select `Custom` export and select `Compression` under `Output`*

Now you have backup of your webpage AND still running webpage itself. There is no such thing as `Cold/Hot` backup as you described.

Comment: http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Database-Backups---Hot-Backup-vs.-Cold-Backup/27348

this is one of many links that says there is!

Comment: @user1834091 I don't think you will ever stop your webpage to do backup. To update database with big changes - yes, there might be advised to make webpage inaccessible

Comment: I understand that .. I am asking how would you go about backing up the files stored outside the database with only their paths inside of it while the users are actually still accessing that database (it doesn't make sense to just leave those files not backed up as the users actually use them and if said files somehow are lost or inaccessible it is a huge inconvenience for the user)

Comment: @user1834091 You can't use MySql to access files, it's impossible. Use FTP (as separate step of backup) to access files and download them to your computer. Or set up some Cron Job to do copies of files regularly